# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a un componente en jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, framework, jetpack-compose

No sé como acceder al componente "Image" en el onClick. Intento acceder a esa image que se genera para poder guardarla en galería del teléfono en el onClick pero no sé como conseguir llegar a ella. Anteriormente en xml para acceder se usaba binding.ImageView, existe algo parecido en Compose? Este sería la parte del código de la que hablo:

````
               
                TextField(modifier = Modifier
    
                value = datos.value,
                onValueChange = { datos.value = it }
            )

            if (!datos.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                Image(
                    bitmap = createQR(datos.value).asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        ...
                        }
                )
            }
            Button(
                onClick = {

                },
                ...```
````

Answer (score 0):

Image es un @Composable y por ende no tiene estado.
Te tocaria tener algo parecido al `createQR(datos.value).asImageBitmap()` en el viewModel que te devuelva el bitmap para poder operar con el.